# Do I need to give credits for the icons by the android Asset Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, copyright-display

My App uses several icons from the Asset Studio from the Android Studio.

When I'm selecting an icon it says: "*These icons are availiable under the CC-BY license*". The official CC Website tells me "You must give appropriate credit".

### **Question:**

How and where (in my app) do I need to do so? Do I just need to add in a link somewhere in my app? Or what exactly are the conditions to use these icons in my app?

Comment: **YES** It says it right in your post. Generally, you use the _About_ screen of your app to list all of the external contributions and licenses. [From CC](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/) `You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made.`

Comment: So sth. like "all Icons used in this app are under the CC-BY license and belong to Google"?

Comment: @MattClark so what link do I need to use? I guess it's not google.com...

Comment: [Check this out](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964). Open source licensing questions can be asked on [OpenSource.SE](//opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES**

According to the [CC-BY license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/):

> Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

*However*, the [Material Design Icon set](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) readme states:

> We have made these icons available for you to incorporate them into your products under the Apache License Version 2.0. Feel free to remix and re-share these icons and documentation in your products. We'd love attribution in your app's about screen, but it's not required. The only thing we ask is that you not re-sell these icons.